# Imported Segments from BigQuery show 0% eligible in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I am trying to build out a test "Imported Segment" to be sure everything is setup correctly before attempting to push an actual notification out to my users.

I've built a segment of the last 1000 users seen in BigQuery using my Firebase Analytics and populated the SegmentMemberships table with the `user_pseudo_id` as the `instance_id`.  I am not touching the `user_pseudo_id` in my app's code, so it should be whatever Firebase uses as its default.

Now that I've successfully imported the segment back into Firebase and tried to target it in the Messaging Console, it's saying that `0% of potential users are eligible for this campaign: <100`.

Is there any kind of editing that needs to be done to the `user_pseudo_id`/`instance_id` so that it can match users in Firebase?  Capitalization?  Prefixes?

Is that estimate of potential users correct?  Does the "<100" estimate mean that there's greater than 0?  I wouldn't be surprised if less than 10% of my users have push notifications enabled but I'm interpreting the "0%" as meaning there are no users at all, which seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `firebase_id` in your Imported Segment table. The `user_pseudo_id` is a different identifier. In order to create segments from bigquery usage data, you'll need to send the `firebase_id` with you analytics data. The `firebase_id` can be set as a user property. Firebase has (at least) three IDs that can easily confuse you:

`user_id` is a custom ID that you are able to set as whatever you like

`firebase_id`: is an ID that is also called an Install ID in some documentation. This is the ID that firebase uses to target specific installs for messaging purposes.

`user_pseudo_id` is an analytics ID that is set for a specific install for a specific user on a specific device